# Convert uint16 Matlab matrix into a Java short[][] using jmatio?

Tags: java, arrays, matlab, mat-file, matio

I am trying to convert a `uint16` Matlab matrix (size: 1109-by-1024) into a Java `short[][]` using the jmatio library. Following is the code:

```
String name     = "array_re";
String fileName = "microsec.mat";
MatFileReader matfilereader = new MatFileReader( fileName );
short[][] mlArrayShort = ((MLInt16) matfilereader.getMLArray( name  
                          )).getArray();
```

However, at the third line, I am getting the following error:

> "com.jmatio.io.MatlabIOException: Incorrect matlab array class: uint16".

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to save the MATLAB array as `int16` instead of `uint16`? Java cannot handle unsigned types.

Comment: If your data have values greater than `intmax('int16')` need to use `int32` or re-scale your `uint16` data to use the negative range,

Comment: @CST-Link. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answers. Yes the problem was that Java does not handle unsigned data types. I converted the matrix from Matlab to signedint16 and read it in Java successfully using the same above code.